# How to truncate a table using greenDAO

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, greendao

does anyone know how I can delete all the contents of a table in greenDao . I do not want to delete the actual table , just the contents equivalent to a sql truncate statement .

Regards

Answer (score 6):

Use `AbstractDao.deleteAll()` method, where `AbstractDao` is the Dao, that represents your model.
This removes the table, but keeps cache.
To clear cache, use:
`DaoSession.clear()`

Comment: I understand what you are saying , however I would like to delete all contents in that table and not the actual table

Comment: Have you tried it? `deleteAll()` deletes table content. `Dao.dropTable()` deletes a table.

Comment: What happens if `deleteAll()` called on empty table. Does `GreenDAO` handles this case?

Comment: Only `SQL` statement `DELETE FROM  [config.tablename]` is run. There should be no problem.